# Escaping a quote in findstr search string

Tags: batch-file, escaping, quotes, findstr

How can I properly escape a quote in a search string when using findstr.exe?

Example:

```
findstr /misc:"namespace=\"" *.cs > ns.txt
```

This outputs to the console, instead of to the file I specified.

I am doing this directly on the command line, not actually in a batch file, though that information might be useful too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I've figured it out:

```
findstr.exe /misc:^"namespace=\^"^" *.cs > ns.txt
```

This seems to give the correct output, even if you have spaces in your search string.  It allows file redirection, piping, and additional literals in the same findstr.exe invocation to work correctly.

The original command in my question doesn't work because both cmd.exe and findstr.exe have special processing for the `"` character.  I ended up with an unmatched set of quotes in cmd.exe's processing.

The new command in my answer works because `^"` allows the quote to pass from cmd.exe to findstr.exe, and `\"` tells findstr.exe to ignore that quote for command processing purposes, and treat it as a character literal.

**Edit**:

Well, my solution was right, but the reason it is correct was totally wrong.  I wrote a small program to test it.

I found out that cmd.exe passes this input to the program when I pass the bad command line:

```
test.exe /misc:namespace=" *.cs > ns.txt
```

With the characters escaped correctly, cmd.exe passes this input to the program (and redirects output to a file):

```
test.exe /misc:namespace=" *.cs
```

Answer (score 5):

Found [Re: FINDSTR search for a couble quote and redirect/pipe the output](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Windows/microsoft.public.windows.server.general/2006-01/msg00697.html)

```
Try this: 

findstr > x.txt /S /I /M /C:"\.\"" *
```

I have no idea why this works.

Doesn't work for piping the output though. See the related link [piping findstr's output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737107/piping-findstrs-output)

Comment: That makes it look like you can do file redirection mid-line, and pass arguments afterwards?  That kind of upsets my whole world of batch file understanding :)

Comment: Yes, redirects are allowed at the front, middle or end of a line, even multiple redirects are allowed, but only the last will become effective.

Answer (score 4):

According to my tests the correct escape character is backslash:

```
c:\Temp>findstr /isc:"session id=\"59620\"" C:\Temp\logs\some*.xml
C:\Temp\logs\some_2016_11_03.xml: <session id="59620" remoteAddress="192.168.195.3:49885"/>
```

Comment: ding! exactly what i needed ! and didn't know you could specify multiple options with one '/' :), nice

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this be just enough:

```
findstr /misc:namespace=^" *.cs > ns.txt
```

?

**EDIT**

If you were searching for a way to pass the `"` character inside a quoted parameter, then it could be (using your example)

```
findstr /misc:"namespace=""" *.cs > ns.txt
```

(the `"` character is repeated twice inside a quoted string).

Comment: For this problem, yes.  For a general purpose problem, such as if you have spaces in your search string, no.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Added solution for a more general problem.

Comment: @Andriy: Check out my answer.  It correctly handles cases such as this - `findstr /c:"this is ""a test""" blah.txt`, when blah.txt contains only the line `this is "a test"`.  Double quoting doesn't solve the problem when spaces are involved.

Comment: @Merlyn: Indeed my solution seems to work only until you add a space somewhere *after* the inner (replicated) double quote. I.e., this still works (displays the echo result): `echo this is "a test"|findstr /c:"this is ""a"`. And this doesn't (complains about not being able to open 'a'): `echo this is "a test"|findstr /c:"this is ""a "`. +1 to your solution, I think you should accept it.

Comment: @Andriy: Thanks for the help, though.  I'd like not to have to add all that escaping-noise...

Comment: Ugh, the windows command line is terrible.  Specifying `""""` (four double-quotes in a row) passes one double-quote as an argument to the called program, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

They must be escaped for both the findstr program and the shell you are using.
https://ss64.com/nt/findstr-escapes.html

So, if run from powershell, your example would be

```
findstr /misc:"namespace=\`"" *.cs > ns.txt
```